# python getattr built-in method executes default arguments

Tags: python, python-2.7, getattr

I dont know if this is something an expected behavior of `getattr` built_in method.
`getattr` executes the default(3rd) argument as well even if the actual argument(2nd) satisfies the condition.
Example:

```
def func():
    print('In Function')

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.param = 12

a = A()
```

When I run `getattr(a, 'param', func())` it gives this result:

```
In Function
12
```

Note the `In Function` which I don't want.

But it works perfectly fine when I execute `getattr(a, 'param1', func())` i.e output

```
In Function
```

But I only want result as `12` if satisfied the condition. Please let me know why `getattr` has such behaviour and can we stop them of doing it (that is not to execute 3rd arg if has 2nd argument), would be appreciated if share the alternate way of doing it in Pythonic way.
One thing that comes in mind first is to check if `param1` exist using `hasattr` and then do the needful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Before `getattr` gets executed, all the passed parameters have to be evaluated. `func()` is one of those parameters and an attempt to evaluate it will execute the `print` statement. Whether the attribute will be found or not, `func()` must be evaluated apriori.

This isn't peculiar to `getattr`, it's how functions and their parameters work in Python.

---

Consider the following:

```
>>> def does_nothing(any_arg): pass
...
>>> def f(): print("I'll get printed")
...
>>>
>>> does_nothing(f())
I'll get printed
```

Function `does_nothing` actually does nothing with the passed parameter. But the parameter has to be evaluated before the function call can go through.

---

The `print` statement however will not affect the outcome of `getattr`; sort of a *side effect*. In the event the attribute is not found the `return` value of the function is used.

Comment: I think this will be an overhead of adding extra function and instead I think I should go with `hasattr` check. Nevertheless Thanks.

Comment: If you don't want `func()` to be evaluated when `a` has attr `param`, you can change to: `getattr(a, 'param', None) or func()`.  Any valid code after `or` becomes *lazy*.

Comment: Thanks @Chang.Jian, this is useful trick. how can I miss this.

Comment: It's not completely equivalent. The code after `or` will also run if the value before the `or` is falsy, like 0 or False